# C#: GetResponse method not a definition for WebRequest

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpwebresponse

**EDIT: I've tried casting both `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` but still no luck.**

My main goal is to communicate with a camera API, pull an image using my C# controller, and display this image on the DOM afterwards. I'm running into a problem with the `GetResponse` method.

> 'WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no
>   extension mothod 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type
>   'WebRequest' could be found.

My code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var username = "myusername";
        var passwd = "mypassword";
        var url = "http://camera-ip-address/api/call/camera=1";

        NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(username, passwd);

        // Create a WebRequest with the specified URL. 
        HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentials;

        // Send the request and wait for a response.
        HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();

        // Return the response.
        return View(myWebResponse);
    }
}
```

**Note**: The IP Address of my WebApp and the IP address of the cameras are not the same so there's a chance for a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error to happen. If anyone has any advice towards this, I would be glad to accept any on how to make that work as well.

Comment: @rene, in the example you've linked, as well as my own shown above, I'm trying to understand, the URL passed into the `Create` method, is that for the API call URL? Or is it for generating my own page to handle the response?

Comment: @Rene I've went ahead and edited my question, trying a cast, but I get the same error.

Comment: @Rene Actually, you bring up a good point, if I'm running this locally on a port in localhost, would that mean that I can't user the `GetResponse` method?

Comment: Do the "http://camera-ip-address/api/call/camera=1" exist?

Comment: @Rene I tried that last approach and it doesn't work, still getting `GetResponse()` method as  undefined. It could be the fact that I'm doing this as an ASP.Net Core project rather than an MVC project. Some assemblies don't come with it.

Comment: @Braiam absolutely,